# (Redux) react-native-debugger not working on custom development client

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, react-native-debugger, redux-devtools-extension

Recently I ejected a Managed Workflow project and now I’m on Bare Workflow, things were going pretty good until now.

I was able to add native libraries and are working OK such as segment’s analytics-react-native and I’ve created a build for both iOS and android devices to run the dev client (instead of Expo Go). But now I wanted to add a composerEnhancer to see my store on react-native-debugger app and after setting it up I just get “no store found. Make sure to follow the instructions” on a browser tab.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, 
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
  )
);

return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Navigation />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I tried same config in a Bare workflow with Exgo Go Client and it’s working fine. But I can’t make it work on Custom Dev Client, any thoughts?